# How do I get a true value when using object_comparison on an empty linked list in my post condition?

Tags: eiffel, post-conditions

I have an assignment that requires me to create an empty linked list `key: LINKED_LIST [KEY]`, another linked list `data_items_1: LINKED_LIST [DATA1]` and a hash table `data_items_2: HASH_TABLE [DATA2, KEY]` in the constructor. The post condition that my professor put was

```
object_equality_for_keys: keys.object_comparison
object_equality_for_data_items_1: data_items_1.object_comparison
object_equality_for_data_items_2: data_items_2.object_comparison
```

When I run the program I get a contract violation. In the debugger it's always pointing to this line of code and I'm not sure why. What is the purpose of this post condition and how do I not violate this contract?
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

The feature `compare_objects` of class `CONTAINER` indicates whether that container uses `=` (reference comparison) or `~` (value/object comparison, which calls `is_equal` internally) when comparing items. You can call `compare_objects` or `compare_references` to configure individual containers and ensure they work the way you need them to.

Comment: So that means somewhere else in my class I'm comparing 
references with those data structures?